# sum rows and columns depending on two values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

I got the following table in Excel (Microsoft Excel 2011 for Mac).

It is basically for controlling issues. It shows a number of persons (employees) that are assigned to specific work-packages that belong to one single project. Now I would like to get an overview about "planned" hours for a single project. The problem is, that it has two sums. First, the sum of work-packages that belong to the project. Second, the sum of persons that belong to the department. So it's a cross-sum over work-packages and departments.

**Question:** I made the second table just as an example (manually). But how to do this with Excel?

**Remark:** Each person has two columns. One contains the planned hours, the other one contains the currently spent hours. I could remove that second column if necessary. It's more important to sum the work-packages and departments.

[image: Controlling]

Comment: Would a pivot table work for you?

Comment: I would prefer a non-pivot table.

Comment: I would suggest a macro then.

Comment: I used sumproduct now